# how to detect if the windows key is pressed?

Tags: .net, winforms, keypress, windows-key

I would like to be able to detect when the windows Key is pressed. I tried with getasynckeystate function bug didnt found the right virtual key.
 thanks for your help !

Comment: Please tag your question correctly. Are you using C# or VB? Is it VB6 or VB.NET? What version?

Answer (score 3):

Check this out:

[Keys Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx)

You're looking for these key codes:

```
LWin    The left Windows logo key (Microsoft Natural Keyboard).
RWin    The right Windows logo key (Microsoft Natural Keyboard).
```

Sample code:

```
Public Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    If (e.Key = Key.LWin Or e.Key = Key.RWin) Then
        MsgBox("Pressed Windows Key")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The key codes are given on the [Keys Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) page:

> LWin  The left Windows logo key (Microsoft Natural Keyboard).
>   RWin    The right Windows logo key (Microsoft Natural Keyboard).

It doesn't indicate whether either (if any) of these codes is obtained when using a keyboard **other** than the Microsoft Natural Keyboard.

If you are using WinForms then you need to trap the [KeyDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx)

If you are using WPF then you need the [Keyboard.KeyDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.keydown.aspx)

Comment: And if it's a console application, you want to call `Console.ReadKey()` and check the value of the returned `ConsoleKeyInfo.Key` property. The values are `ConsoleKey.LeftWindows` and `ConsoleKey.RightWindows`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `GetAsyncKeyState`, the values you're looking for are defined in WinUser.h as `VK_LWIN` and `VK_RWIN':  0x5B and 0x5C, respectively.